# Screen doesn't appear right in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I made a Listbox widget panel with a button panel on one screen, and I fill it with pubsub but for some reason the first time I load the screen it looks like this:

[image]

The screen goes back to normal once I expand the application, please let me know if something is unclear.

the code:

```
class StationsPanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent, frame):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                      size=(500,400),
                      style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

    hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.listbox = wx.ListBox(self)

    # subscribe with pub sub to fill the list
    pub.subscribe(self.fill_list, "fill_list")
    hbox.Add(self.listbox, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
   
    self.SetSizer(hbox)

    self.Centre()
    self.Layout()
    self.Hide()


def fill_list(self, stations):
    """

    :param stations: list of mac addresses of the stations
    :return: fills the list
    """
    # add all the stations to list
    for mac in stations:
        self.listbox.Append(mac)

    self.Layout()
```

P.S I do switch the size of the frame and panel when I switch to this screen (maybe it's connected)

Comment: To see a basic app [look here](https://pastebin.com/61EGt2xZ). Add the minimum amount of code to this app to demonstrate your problem

Comment: You forgot to add `listbox` to `hbox`. You probably also need to review the code that defines the relationship between `StationsPanel` instance and its parent.